# Having a JSP in embedded Jetty 8.1.2 call a POST method

Tags: jsp, post, jetty

I have the following JSP code contained in an embedded Jetty server which doesnt have either a web.xml and is exported as a jar file, not as a WAR file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="tech" class="com.sgi.jetty.webapp.TechServlet" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="tech" property="*"/>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tech Diags</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Tech Diags</h1>
<br>
<form METHOD="post" action="doPost">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>External Id</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="extId" value="<%= tech.getExternalId() %>" style="width:250px"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address List</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="addrList" value="<%= tech.getAddressList() %>" style="width:600px"/> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Which I need to call a POST method in TechServlet.  I can get the JSP to reference the servlet code so that the various fields show the stored values but I cant get updates to be reflected back to the server.

Does anybody know how to get an embedded jetty server to recognize POST calls in a jsp?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mix up with this:

```
<form METHOD="post" action="doPost">
```

"doPost" is the url, not the method in your servlet